# AWS API Gateway, Python Lambda and HTTP status

Tags: python, http, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, http-status

I'm struggling to understand how to setup proper http status codes and error messages using AWS API Gateway and a Lambda Function (python) as Integration type.

I'm working with a simple example, here the details:

**Lambda function**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    return_json = {}
    if event["request-number"] == "":
        raise Exception("Error request-number can't be empty")
    elif event["request-number"] == "3":
        raise Exception("Value not accepted")
    else:
        return_json = {"service-activated": "TRUE"}

    return return_json
```

**API**
/resourcetest
POST

This is integrated with the lambda above.

**Goal**: return HTTP 400 and body with message *Error request-number can't be empty*  when request-number = "".

**Implementation**:

1. I've created a new method response 400
2. In the lambda Error Regex I've mapped Error.* so to catch that string
3. In the body mapping templates: I've created a content-type as application/json and as a template I've used (there's an hashtag symbol before set, but that screw up the formatting of this page, so I've omitted it):

   set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
   {
     "message" : $input.json('$.errorMessage')
   }
4. I've checked to have the http status 400 in the method response (and I have it)

**Test**
Through the AWS API Gateway console I've tested to have HTTP 400 and the message *Error request-number can't be empty* in the body. Good I achieved what I wanted:

[image]

I've decided to test also through Postman and the Chrome plugin Restlet Client and what I've got is http status 200 and error message not formatted properly:

[image]

Now, this is quite weird: from the AWS API Console all is good and nice, from an external service nothing work as expected.

Has anyone had to deal with something similar ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you re-deployed your API?

Comment: Oh, you are right. I kept thinking at what was wrong without thinking about the deploy.
Thank you Scott!